# Pointer on how to draw this custom view in Android

Tags: android, drawing, android-custom-view

I am not very familiar with drawing tottally custom views in Android so I would need few pointers. Basically I would like to draw this view shown below:

[image: Watch face]

So what I did was to draw a circle with a Paint:

```
Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeWidth(50);
```

But then I got completely lost when it came to adding the dashes evenly spaced with a top, bottom, left and right dash longer.

Can anyone give me a hint of how to approach this please?

Comment: You are gonna have some fun math involved with getting that one to work... Gonna need to draw a circle, and then I would think add dashes based on some mathematical formula that places the dashes in the right position.

Comment: Do you need to draw it in code or could you make the image in Inkscape then export it as a png or convert to an XML drawable?

Comment: @Jerry101 all in code

Comment: @zgc7009 thanks for pointer I have got basic idea

Answer (score 3):

You really wouldn't even need to use a custom view for this (although if it starts to have behavior, you probably should move to one). Just make a custom drawable, and draw to the canvas as needed. A working example is below, with some commented caveats.

Basically, just draw the ring (just draw a circle with a thick stroke), then draw a tick on the bottom of the canvas, then continue rotating the canvas for each additional tick.

```
public class ClockDrawable extends Drawable {
    // TODO Sample variables, these don't take density into account
    private static final int TICK_COUNT = 48;
    private static final int RING_THICKNESS = 50;
    private static final int TICK_THICKNESS = 10;
    private static final int LONG_TICK = 30;
    private static final int SHORT_TICK = 10;

    private final Paint mRingPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    private final Paint mTickPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    public ClockDrawable() {
        mRingPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mRingPaint.setStrokeWidth(RING_THICKNESS);
        mRingPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        mTickPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        mTickPaint.setStrokeWidth(TICK_THICKNESS);
        mTickPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        final Rect bounds = getBounds();
        final int h = bounds.height();
        final float cx = bounds.exactCenterX();
        final float cy = bounds.exactCenterY();
        final float rotationAnglePerTick = 360f / TICK_COUNT;

        // Draw the ring (using the stroke, offset by half of the stroke width
        // since the stroke is drawn around the circle (not inside or outside)
        canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, cx - (mRingPaint.getStrokeWidth() / 2), mRingPaint);

        for (int i = 0; i < TICK_COUNT; i++) {
            // Check if it's one of the ticks on the top, left, right, or bottom
            float tickHeight = i % (TICK_COUNT / 4) == 0 ? LONG_TICK : SHORT_TICK;

            // For each tick, rotate the canvas by the angle per tick and the tick
            // number, then draw a rectangle along the bottom. Since the canvas is
            // rotating, you can just continue to draw a simple rectangle and not
            // worry about angles. The canvas should rotate around the center point.
            //
            // Not covered here: clipping the ticks to stay within the ring bounds.
            canvas.save();

            canvas.rotate(rotationAnglePerTick * i, cx, cy);
            canvas.drawRect(
                    cx - (TICK_THICKNESS / 2),
                    h - tickHeight,
                    cx + (TICK_THICKNESS / 2),
                    h,
                    mTickPaint);

            canvas.restore();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        mRingPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
        mTickPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        mRingPaint.setColorFilter(cf);
        mTickPaint.setColorFilter(cf);
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is final Rect bounds = getBounds(); giving me method not found, even if the Rect class is imported?

Answer (score 0):

(1) One approach is to draw the thick black circle, then draw small white lines on top. Compute all the line endpoints using either trig or a [DDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_differential_analyzer_(graphics_algorithm)), or use a rotation matrix.

Call `clipPath()` before drawing the lines so they'll stop cleanly at the outer edge of the circle.

(2) It's probably easier to use a [DashPathEffect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/DashPathEffect.html) to draw circles with a dashed line: `drawCircle(float cx, float cy, float radius, Paint paint)`.

With this approach, draw the outer ring of the circle using a dashed path effect with short dashes, then draw then middle ring using a dashed path effect with long dashes, and finally draw the inner ring using a solid paint.

You'll need to compute the right `DashPathEffect` intervals (an *off* distance and an *on* distance) that gives the right "line" thickness, distance between "lines", and matches up at the end of the circle.